# Bittrex API not returning all values

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I trying to put together a simple Google spreadsheet that fetches data from the Bittrex API. I started from an example that fetched fields from */public/getticker*, that gets the last, highest, and lowest prices, and changed it to instead request from */public/getmarketsummary* and */public/getmarketsummaries* (tried both). It'll retrieve the last price, but everything else is parsed as *undefined*

[Screenshot of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOpGC.jpg)

I'm not a programmer, so apologies if I'm using the wrong words or text styles.

Here's the script.

```
  function updateBittrex()
{  
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cryptoassets");  
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
  var currencyPair =  sheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=' + currencyPair);
  var bittrexData=JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
if (bittrexData.success = true) {
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("SUCCESS");
  } else {
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("FAIL");
  } 

  sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(bittrexData.result.Last);
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(bittrexData.result.High);
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 4).setValue(bittrexData.result.Low);
  sheet.getRange(i+1,5).setValue(bittrexData.result.Volume);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- In order to retrieve "the last, highest, and lowest prices (and Volume?)", you can use `https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary` as the endpoint.
- `result` you want is an array.
- In your case, the efficiency of your script becomes high by using `setValues()` instead of `setValue()`.

The modified script reflected above is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function updateBittrex() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cryptoassets");  
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    var currencyPair =  sheet.getRange(i+1,1).getValue();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=' + currencyPair); // Modified
    var bittrexData=JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    if (bittrexData.success = true) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("SUCCESS");
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 6).setValue("FAIL");
    }
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 2, 1, 4).setValues( // Modified
      [[
        bittrexData.result[0].Last,
        bittrexData.result[0].High,
        bittrexData.result[0].Low,
        bittrexData.result[0].Volume
      ]]
    );
  }
}
```

### References :

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Developer's Guide - Api for Bittrex](https://bittrex.com/home/api)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.